# Alias web api request model

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use ajax call on asp.net web api where i want to alias the request model property name.

However, when i post the value back to the server and receive it as request, it does not work as expected. what i intend to achieve is as follow: 
When i pass the data valueA back to web api, it will mapped to MemberName. Not sure where i did wrong.

THis is what something i expect.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '..',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 'valueA': 'ABC' },
  success: {}
})
```

```html
public class MemberProfile {
  [JSONProperty('valueA')]
  public string MemberID { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMemberProfile(MemberProfile request)
{
}
```

Comment: Is `request` null when you hit that action?

Comment: @Glitch100 yes request null when hit that acton

Comment: For the sake of testing, if you remove the `[JSONProperty]` and try posting up MemberId, does it get mapped?

Comment: @Glitch100 yeah it mapped

Comment: @Glitch100 so u know what the problem is?

Comment: do all your projects reference Newtonsoft (if thats the JSON lib you are using) and is the 'class' in a seperate project? And have you tried using `[DataMember(Test)]` instead?

Comment: @Glitch100 the newtonsoft is working correctly because it do response valueA when i use it in response data member. Yes, I do try using datacontract and datamember as well but is not working.

Comment: Is `MemberProfile` in a seperate project other than Web?

Comment: @Glitch100 is in same project under Model folder.

Comment: I have sadly had this problem before but was able to solve it using the things I have mentioned. Try updating newtonsoft? Also what version of MVC/WebAPI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should change you JavaScript code to :

```
$.ajax({
  url: '..',
  contentType:'application/json', //here
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({ valueA: "ABC" }), //here
  success: {}
})
```